# How to use role ID's and Member ID's discord js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have also used else if statements for more roles so I would like to be able to use either the role ID or the user ID for the const.

```
const { DiscordAPIError } = require("discord.js")
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { Client, Attachment, Message, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { newInMsgEvtInterceptor } = require("fix/handlers/inMsgEvtInterceptor");

module.exports = {
    name: `say`,
    aliases: ['send'],
    cooldown: 10,
    description: "sends a message through the bot",
    execute (client, message, args){
        let { content, member, channel } = message
        let timeout;
        
        const Sradmin = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "SR.Admin");
        
//----------------------------------------------------------
        if (message.member.roles.cache.has(Sradmin.id)) {
        
            message.delete({timeout: 100})
            message.channel.send(`${args.join(" ")}** **`);
//----------------------------------------------------------   

        } else {   
            message.channel.send(`You cant use this command`);
    
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I would like to replace the name of the role in this case SR.Admin with the ID of the role: 1044399351742611516
As well as being able to add custom users to be able to use this command by using there ID: 927305865428611172

Comment: Your question is very unclear, can you elaborate what you want to do? Also, if you only need the role id of the "SR.Admin" role (e.g. this role is the always the same and will never change), you can just copy the id and paste it into your `message.member.roles.cache.has()` call, instead of fetching the role for no reason and using that id. Same thing if you want to use a constant user id, just paste the user id as the argument, no need to fetch the user when you only need the same info every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For role ID'S I can use this

```
const role1 = message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "1044399351742611516")
```

For Users I can use

```
const admins = ['927305865428611172'] // You can add more user ID'S in this box
```

and

```
if(admins.includes(message.author.id))
```

The final code would look something like this

```
const { DiscordAPIError } = require("discord.js")
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { Client, Attachment, Message, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { newInMsgEvtInterceptor } = require("fix/handlers/inMsgEvtInterceptor");

module.exports = {
    name: `say`,
    aliases: ['send'],
    cooldown: 10,
    description: "sends a message through the bot",
    execute (client, message, args){
        let { content, member, channel } = message
        let timeout;
        
        const admins = ['927305865428611172']

        const role1 = message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "1044399351742611516")

        
//----------------------------------------------------------
        if(admins.includes(message.author.id)) {
        
            message.delete({timeout: 100})
            message.channel.send(`${args.join(" ")}** **`);
//----------------------------------------------------------
        else if (message.member.roles.cache.has(role1.id)) {
        
            message.delete({timeout: 100})
            message.channel.send(`${args.join(" ")}** **`);
//----------------------------------------------------------   

        } else {   
            message.channel.send(`You cant use this command`);
    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).